# OpenGL load texture without or with static device context?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I want to create opengl 2d library, where textures as well as windows are encapsulated as objects. Is it possible to create dummy static DC and make it current when loading textures? All of the windows would have same `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` as the static one. This way, users of the library would not have to create window prior to loading textures or passing windows as parameters to textures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create dummy static DC and make it current when loading textures?

Sort of. As long as the visual formats of the device contexts are compatible with each other, you can bind a OpenGL render context created for this visual format to any of these device contexts.

So you can perfectly fine create a window, with a DC that's never shown on the screen (always kept hidden, size of 0×0) and use that for background OpenGL operations. You can also create a secondary OpenGL context, have it share its namespace with the primary context, make it current on the hidden window on a separate worker thread, so that you can asynchronously perform OpenGL operations (like loading textures) while the main context is used for other things.